# mini cart not showing items

Tags: mini-cart, magento-2.0.7

I have installed magento 2.0.7 and override `minicart.phtml` file in my custom theme. After adding product in cart ,click on the Minicart icon in the header, the content area of the minicart displays

> "You have no items in your shopping cart".

But the product is added to the cart. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is magento default bug in magento-2.0.7

You can get more information about it from here :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4170

This issue resolved in latest magento version, you can resolve it by upgrade you magento version.

Answer (score 0):

can you check is your cache disable?

Because it seems that the issue comes when caching off

In my case. If I enable cache, the mini cart works as it should. Cool.

For Magento upgrade follow below URL:

https://wp.me/p4FAWA-6X